# Como Bindear la direccion de una imagen en el SRC con Angular7

Tags: angular, binding

Cuando intento enviar una propiedad de un objeto a mi template, todo carga bien excepto la *SRC* de la imagen la cual parece que no la reconoce.

aquí esta mi template:

---

```
<div class="card" style="width:400px">
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{producto.imagen}}" alt="{{producto.nombre}}" style="width:100%">
<div class="card-body">
  <h4 class="card-title">{{producto.nombre}}</h4>
  <p class="card-text">{{producto.descripcion}}</p>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Mas Informacion</a>
</div>
```

Todo bindea bien a excepción de

> src="{{producto.imagen}}"

De la etiqueta **img** Me gustaria saber cual es la notación correcta. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tu notación es correcta `<img  src={{imagen}} />`  Al menos para la versión de Angular JS. No sé si uses Angular CLI, pero no debe cambiar mucho.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h1>{{ nombre }}</h1>
<img  src={{imagen}} />
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.nombre= "Codemonkey";
    $scope.imagen = "https://www.playcodemonkey.com/assets/landing/features3.png"
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Para Angular 2+, si tienes una variable del controlador llamada `this.image="tu url aqui"`, entonces en el código HTML debes colocar `<img [src]="image">`.